# Expressing discrete random variable in terms of another discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, discrete-data

I have a Binomially distributed discrete random variable $X$, so that $X{\sim}(n,0.09896)$, where $n$ can be any positive integer. $X$ represents, say, the number of people who arrive at a restaurant in a night.

Following with the restaurant example, I have a "profit function" that takes in some values and find the profit for the night. The profit is $P=people\space{\times}\space X\times\space{cost \space of \space  meal} \space - \space operating  \space costs$.

My attempt above is a variable that has $X$ as part of it, because the number of people who go are not known - it's probabilistic. The number of people who go to the restaurant in a night could be 10, 20, 30, any value from 0 to $n$. I need a way to express this in an equation, while also having other operations (such as the subtraction of the operating costs). I attempted above to express this, but I'm unsure how correct it is.

My question is, is profit equation above valid?

If so, can I treat $P$ as a discrete random variable, because it's constructed with one (e.g. by taking the mean, constructing a probability distrubution, etc.), or are there limitations? What if I have, say $P=aX\space+\space bX\space+c$?

If it's not valid, what notation/concepts can I use to represent what I want

Comment: (1) In what sense are you concerned that the profit equation -- which is purely a statement about your restaurant -- could not be "valid"? (2) When a random variable can attain only a finite number of values, it must be discrete and so must be any function of it.

Comment: If $X$ is nr. of people, then how do you define _people_? Does _operating expense_ depend on other variables (such as $X$ and _cost of meal_)? If so, how?

Comment: @BruceET no, operating costs are constant - it's, say, the cost of the live band, staff, etc. and does not depend on the number of people. People are the number of meals sold (assuming one meal per person, and everyone buys the same meal for the same price, with no tips)

Comment: @whuber (1) I'm concerned that I'm not accurately representing that the profit is "probabilistic". Every night the profit will be different, depending on the number of guests. The number of guests is a discrete random variable, however, and I'm not sure how to show that in the profit equation